# Getting [Object Object] in angular application

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

Getting **[Object Object]** in angular form and also dropdown(select) not set to default 0 index. While in case of edit everything working fine. Do I need to initialize model properties for this create page?

[image]

**Edit** :  **ngModelChange** not calling the function **doNameChange**.

**Component:**

```
  export class User {
  Id: number;
  Name: string;
  Gender: string;    
}
this.user = {
      Id: 0,
      Name: '',
      Gender: ''
}
doNameChange(event) {
    debugger;
    console.log(event); // logs model value
  }
```

**Html:**

```
 <form (ngSubmit)="save(f.value, f.valid)" #f="ngForm" novalidate materialize>      
      <input id="Name" (ngModelChange)="doNameChange($event)" name="Name" #Name="ngModel" type="text" class="validate form-control" required minlength="3" [(ngModel)]="user.Name">
      <select id="Gender"  name="Gender" #Gender="ngModel" class="validate form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.Gender" required>
          <option value="">-- Select Gender --</option>
          <option value="Male">Male</option>
          <option value="Female">Female</option>
        </select>
    </form>
```

Comment: Remove ngmodel when you use reactive forms`

Comment: @Vega, I want to want to watch an object change.. wt to do then?

Comment: You look at the documentation for both, and chose one. And please, be more specific about your issue, because apart from the usage of both template driven forms and reactive forms, I don't see any issue in your code.

Comment: ok @trichetriche will take care of it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using reactive forms, don't use ngModel which is for template based forms.
If you need to listen to the changes:

```
ngÒnInit(){
   this.employeeForm = this._fb.group({
      EmployeeId: 0,
      Name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
      Gender: ['', [Validators.required]]  //dropdown
   });
   this.onChanges();
}
...

onChanges(): void {
  this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
        console.log(val);
  });
}

 //or:
onChanges(): void {
  this.myForm.get('name').valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
    console.log(val);
  });
}
```

Comment: pls also check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50699435/how-to-show-loader-on-each-service-call-in-angular

Comment: not working @Vega, I have modified question and added(in Edit part) what I have changed as per your answer..

Comment: In my answer I suggested to remove ngModel. As for the code you pasted, it should work. What is not working? It doesn't follow the changes? Could you make a demo so I can see the rest of your class?

Comment: What doesn't work? What do you expect? It seems to work for me: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rktfh8

Comment: not printing value on console, don't know why.. Do it require any declaration or any import.. is this hello component required to in my app?

Comment: m not working in app.component may be something required to import on other component..

Comment: As much I don't see your whole code, or at least [mcve], I cannot guess what's going on. Compare your code with this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rktfh8. Or fork it and update to show what's going on

Comment: its working, yesterday didn't work, even i cleared temp files browser cache and rebuild the code as well. Today i started my project its already working.. Thanks @Vega..